# Mounting additional hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, mount, hard-drive

[how can I stop this screen appearing at boot?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Uzv.jpg)

Context - I have absolutely no idea if I've done this the correct way but this is what I've done. I bought a new SSD, I fitted the new SSD to my pc, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu onto my new SSD then I formatted the original hard drive and partitioned it (the original hard drive had Ubuntu on it)

Now at boot I'm getting the option to boot between Ubuntu & Ubuntu but I've wiped Ubuntu from the old original HDD.

I haven't mounted it yet as I'm still reading and learning on how to do so. Will this fix the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Boot Repair in the second Ubuntu (the first is anyway formatted, it just appears in that menu) following 2nd option from [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Then apply Recommended Repair, restart and old entry should be gone.

Comment: Ahaa I needed to update the grub! ,  "Sudo update-grub " fixed my problem :-)

Comment: @FakeBedLinen that is indeed the only thing that is needed: tell grub about the new situation. Feel free to post this as an answer for the peruse of future readers. Please also edit the title of your question, which is not reflecting your actual question. This site is not a forum, but a Q&A site trying to build quality documentation for users based on user experiences.